# Can I define two <p> elements, in different html documents with the same IDs?

Tags: html

I would like to know if this is good practice, or if this is a wrong thing to do.

Thank you

Comment: No. Use a class instead. An `id` attribute value is meant to be unique within a document.

Comment: Unique on the entire website?

Comment: What are you using the ID for?   If it's for data, I think it's fine, if it is to style the element, then a class is more appropriate.

Comment: You can, as far as they not in one document. Since you asked for "different html documents". Limit is 1 unique id to 1 document/page. So id must be unique to document page, not to entire website.

Comment: I was trying to use the same JavaScript function for these two <p>  elements, using getElementById. Then I don't know if it is the best to do

Comment: @DouglasOliveira If the function serve same purpose that basically a must. So for example you have function which on click display some message to user, and for all element with id "#someid" it must be same, then it sure right one thing to do.

Comment: @zr9 Thanks, that´s the idea of my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they only are different because they are in a different document, I would even go as far as to say they are not different. Of course you can give them the same ID. We do it with headers and footers all the time, why not with p-elements? Just don't add the same ID more then once in one document.

Regarding the question if this is good practice or not, that entirely depends on the use case and context.

Comment: Thank you Rein, so I think in my case it is not a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

You surely can. It actually helps when you want same kind of behavior for your DOM elements on different pages.

You can have common CSS and JS files for these HTML documents containing the code for elements with same ID's or classes. Reduces duplication of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jairaj

Answer (score 0):

id=identifier. One document can have only one unique id. So two documents can have the same id once in each document.

Think of #header. Multiple html documents will have #header. But only once in each document.

Although when duplicate id's are present in a document, browsers parse the code fine without complaining. But still invalid.

Comment: I never thought about the multiple #header ids, it answers my question. Thanks